# c++ inheritance not recognized

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

Is there some solution or I have to keep exactly class types?

//header file

```
Class Car {
public:
    Car();
    virtual ~Car();
};

class Bmw:Car {
public:
    Bmw();
    virtual ~Bmw();
};

void Start(Car& mycar) {};
```

//cpp file

```
Car::Car(){}
Car::~Car() {}

Bmw::Bmw()
    :Car::Car(){}
Bmw::~Bmw() {}

int main() {
    Car myCar;
    Bmw myBmw;

    Start(myCar); //works
    Start(myBmw); //!! doesnt work

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is `Start` not a method of car?

Comment: Also, you don't need to refer to Car as Car::Car(), it is fine to just refer to it as Car. `Bmw::Bmw() : Car(){}` is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

C++ defaults to private inheritance, so, you need to declare Bmw as:

```
class Bmw:public Car
```

Also, to be completely accurate, you should really have `Start` as a virtual method of `Car` and override it as needed in descendant classes. :)

Answer (score 8):

You should write `class Bmw : public Car`.

What you want to have here is public inheritance, but not a private one (which is default for classes in `C++`).

Answer (score 5):

You have `Bmw` inheriting privately from `Car`, which prevents converting a `Bmw` reference to a `Car` reference. Change the definition to:

```
class Bmw : public Car
```

Answer (score 4):

You need **public inheritance** - it represents **IS A** relationship between derived and base types. As in *bmw IS A car*, while **private inheritance** (the default when not explicitly specified and what you have here) represents *implemented in terms of* relationship.

Try:

```
class Bmw: public Car
{
    // ...
];
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm no mechanic, but `class Bmw: public Car` should fix you up and have you on the road to understanding inheritance in no time!

Inheritance is `private` by default for `class`es (`public` for `struct`s).